# Groovy 2.1 - directorySize method not found

Tags: grails, groovy

I upgraded a Groovy compiler to 2.1.6, but I still have exception on calling directorySize method:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.io.File.directorySize() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

What I'm trying to do:

```
def myDir = new File("path")
if (myDir.exists()){
    println "directorySize(): " + myDir.directorySize()
}
```

Comment: Weird, works fine for me on grovy 2.2.1, jdk 7

Comment: Its no longer underlined as groovy 1.8 but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You tagged this as Grails, so I assume you're trying to do this in a Grails project. This method was added in Groovy 2.1, but the version of Groovy used in Grails is fixed - you can't change it. You can use whatever compiler in your IDE you want, but that doesn't affect what will work during run-app or in a deployed war. Grails 2.3 uses Groovy 2.1, but Grails 2.2 uses Groovy 2.0 (e.g. Grails 2.2.4 uses Groovy 2.0.8).

You could easily write your own method based on the Groovy implementation. That code is [here](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/ResourceGroovyMethods.java#L112).